# ¿Cómo realizar unescape de una cadena de JSON en Java de Android?

Tags: java, android, json

Me encuentro que las peticiones de API/RESTful recibidas con `JSon` algunos caracteres vienen escapados, como por ejemplo si dentro de una cadena hay un salto de linea `\\n`.

El problema viene que los `TextViews` solo muestran el salto de linea si es `\n`, de momento escapo los caracteres usando la función `replace`.

```
String _title;
...

_title = jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("title");
_title.replace("\\n","\n");
```

Mi pregunta es ¿si existe una función `unescape` para escapar código recibido en `JSON`?

Comment: ¿De casualidad `TextViews`está mostrando el caracter `\\` antes del cambio de línea? o simplemente està ignorando el cambio de línea?

Comment: TextView los \n realiza perfectamente el cambio de linea, pero me encuentro que cuando recibo json como viene \\n eso no se lo come, se debe primero pasar los \\n a \n, me pregunto si hay alguna función unescape que lo haga para todos los caracteres que se hayan escapado en JSon.

Comment: Hola, encontré [esto](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11610833/1913893) puedes verificar si te funciona?.

Comment: Me estas repitiendo el mismo texto que tu pregunta, pero te preguntaba si el texto se mostraba como \ y luego cambio de línea. Lo pregunto porque la codificación \\n está correcta dentro de JSON. El primer \ escapa al segundo \ para convertirse en uno solo al extraer el string de algún key o value. Luego solo quedaría \n que corresponde al cambio de línea

Comment: Es posible que en realidad no recibas doble backslash sino triple backslash? \\\n . Ya que esa cadena decodificada sería \<cambio de linea> no el \n esperado. El `TextViews` entonces podría ignorar el carácter \n y no la cadena "\n" y convertirse en simplemente \ lo que haría que al final no se muestre ningún cambio de línea

Comment: me muestra \n dentro del textView, es decir sin realizar salto de linea.
probare con lo que ha enviado @Alan JONObject.escape("your string");

Comment: @Webserveis pudiste probarlo?

Comment: @Alan parece ser que el objeto JSONObject de Android, no tiene la función escape

Comment: claro, verifica que librería utilizas de donde deriva el JSON Object para así identificar mejor la solución, me apresuré en responder la pregunta.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes intentar con esto:

```
jArray.getJSONObject(i).escape("title")
```

[Ver clase JSONObject](http://juliusdavies.ca/json-simple-1.1.1-javadocs/org/json/simple/JSONObject.html#escape(java.lang.String))

[Ejemplos](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/EncodingExamples)

**Esto depende de que libería utilices**

Otra librería por ejemplo:

```
org.codehaus.jettison.json
```

Puedes usar la función `.quote("text")`, [ver aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8789865/1913893).

Acuérdate, fíjate que librería utilizas antes.

> Para agregar o cargar una librería en android studio, ver [esta
>   respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/2927/225) de [@AngelAngel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/24/angel-angel)

Comment: No ser como cargar la libreria JSONObject en Android Studio

Comment: @Webserveis te dejo como hacerlo en esta direccion -> http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/2926/a%C3%B1adir-biblioteca-library-libreria-en-android-studio/2927#2927, pense ponerlo como comentario pero era muy largo y añadirelo a la pregunta de Alan, seria mas dificil de encontrar para futuros usuarios. Saludos

Comment: excelente @AngelAngel gracias! puedo agregar el link a la respuesta?

Comment: si claro, puede poner algo como. Para lo que usted pregunta de como usar o cargar la libreria puede mirar: y pones el link o algo asi. O lo puedes aclarar como comentario como mejor lo veas. (yo borrare este cometario). Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza la clase [**URLDecoder**](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/java/net/URLDecoder.html), agregando la codificación correspondiente:

```
String _title;
...
_title = URLDecoder.decode(jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("title"), "UTF-8");
```