# Añadir biblioteca (library libreria) en Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Como puedo añadir una `library` usando `gradle` o no, en este caso en particular se trata de añadir la biblioteca para poder usar objetos del tipo `JSONObject` para poder probar un codigo.

Pregunta realizada en base a esta repuesta/pregunta:

[¿Cómo realizar unescape de una cadena de JSON en Java de Android?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/2821/c%C3%B3mo-realizar-unescape-de-una-cadena-de-json-en-java-de-android/2832#2832)

Comment: @Webserveis te dejo como hacerlo , pense ponerlo como comentario pero era muy largo y añadirelo a la pregunta de Alan, seria mas dificil de encontrar para futuros usuarios. Saludos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para el JSONObject, que es la que usaremos de caso:

Si conoces la direccion en este caso seria 'org.json:json:20151123' donde los numero corresponden a la version de la misma, esa es la que usaremos, si no podemos consultar en esta pagina:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20151123

Por ejemplo donde puede ver varias instruciones seleccionamos la que trata sobre `gradle` y veremos algo similar a lo anterior ('org.json:json:20151123').

Ahora en tu proyecto abrimos el `build.gradle file` y añadimos la siguiente instruccion junto con la que obtubimos anteriormente. (`compile 'nombreLibraryDireccion'`)

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //..
    compile 'org.json:json:20151123'
}
```

sincronizamos y deberia de funcionarle, tener presente no tener activada la opcion offline para gradle en las preferencias.

---

Tambien puede añadirla de la siguiente manera, obteniendo el `.jar` de la `library` que deses en este caso seguimos con la anterior, obtenido el jar despues de descargarlo en nuestro equipo.

```
Nombre : json-20151123.jar
```

Abrimos y `copiamos` el fichero json-20151123.jar en la siguiente ruta:

```
../suProyecto/app/libs/
```

Ahora en el `build.gradle file` y añadimos la siguiente instruccion (`compile files ('libs/nombreDelFichero.jar');`):

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    //
    compile files ('libs/json-20151123.jar');
}
```